# Error with pycurl when sending a GET request (1010)

Tags: python, request, pycurl

I would like to use pycurl to send requests to the FTX Exchange.
I have tried with

```
import pycurl
import certifi
from io import BytesIO

buffer = BytesIO()
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'https://ftx.com/api')
c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, buffer)
c.setopt(c.CAINFO, certifi.where())
c.perform()
c.close()

body = buffer.getvalue()
print(body.decode('iso-8859-1'))
```

but I get an error

```
error code: 1010
```

Does anyone know where this error is coming from? I guess it has to do with the certificate bundle that I set with `c.setopt(c.CAINFO, certifi.where())`

Answer (score 0):

it seems like the website using web application firewall 'WAF' like Cloudflare  you need to add User-Agent Header to your code everything will work fine i tested it on number of websites

```
custom_headers = ['User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0/8mqLkJuL-86']

c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, custom_headers)
```